# "Cannot determine operating system" error

Tags: osx

I have a OSX 10.6.8 and installed a LINUX version of Mathematica in my mac.  When I try to open it with X11 or Terminal, it claims that "mathematica cannot determine operating system".  I cannot figure out how to tell it what the OS is (I'm expecting it to be something like `linux32 mathematica`).  I've looked everywhere for help, but nothing; I'm sure it's easy, also. How do I run Mathematica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run Linux programs under OS X - they have to be specifically compiled for OS X. It is exactly the same as trying to run a Windows program on Linux - it can't be done without an emulator like WINE. If you want to run Mathematica on your machine, I'd suggest either obtaining an OS X version of it (the best option in terms of performance) or installing a virtual machine program like VMWare Fusion, and then installing Linux as a VM.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks for clearing this up.  I've installed VirtualBox and I'll work from there.